# CIFS permission issues when mounting a NTFS partition

Tags: permissions, group, ntfs, cifs

I'm attempting to mount an NTFS file share.

```
sudo mount.cifs //address.fileshare.com/TestMount /home/me/TestMount -o username=MyUserName,domain=MyDomain,uid=MyUserName,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777, noperm
```

The mount is successful:

```
mount -l | grep address

//address.fileshare.com/TestMounts on /home/me/TestMount type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=MyUserName,domain=MyDomain,uid=xxxxx,forceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

I get an error when attempting to run `ar` anywhere in the drive.

```
cd /home/me/TestMount/Test && ar -r test.a file1.o file2.o

ar: creating test.a

ar: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: No more archived files
```

I'm able to run this on a local drive as well as the same drive on windows/Cygwin.

I'm able to create files with `touch`.

`uname -a` returns:

```
Linux my_node 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 27 04:30:9 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`ls -la` returns:

```
drwx------. 2 username     **groupid1** 4.0K Mar 19  2019 .
drwx------. 4 username     **groupid1** 4.0K Mar 19 08:51 ..
-rwx------. 1 username     **groupid2** 8.1K Mar 19  2019 file1.o
-rwx------. 1 username     **groupid2** 8.1K Mar 19  2019 file2.o
-rwx------. 1 username     **groupid2**    0 Mar 19  2019 stB914Gl
```

where `stB914Gl` is the temp file created by `ar`.

I've been told the permissions may not be accurate because of the NTFS partition.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit your question with the result of `uname -a`? Could you try to list some files from within the share with `ls -lha`?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for your help.  Also thanks for your edits.  Looks a lot beter.

Comment: `ar` - yuck! Maybe this is it: `f

Truncate names in the archive. GNU ar will normally permit file names of any length. This will cause it to create archives which are not compatible with the native ar program on some systems. If this is a concern, the f modifier may be used to truncate file names when putting them in the archive. `

Comment: Thanks @Seamus.  I just tried  `ar -r -f test.a file1.o file2.o` with the same results.

Comment: Except for `ar`, is the share behavior as expected?

Comment: @Paradox eh.  I've noticed a few quirks.  `cp` from a make file fails.  Also, it seems `git` has a problem creating/deleting `index.lock`  I didn't include those in the post since the errors they give aren't clear.  But they do have a common feature, programs (make, ar, git) fail when creating files.

Comment: @zsnafu That's what I suspected. But you said that `touch` was working properly, right?

Comment: @Paradox That's correct.  Also, it seems like GCC is able to put out object files, as well as Ruby throwing out ascii files, in the same make script